# How to get the v-for index in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component like bellow:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="there I want get the for-loop index"  >

</div>

... 

data(){
  items: [{name:'a'}, {name:'b'}...]
}
```

How can I get the index when I execute the for-loop in my vue.js?

Comment: Bear in mind that using the loop index isn't really any better than just omitting the key entirely. The ideal choice of key is something that uniquely identifies each item in the array/object.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Declare an `index` variable:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.name">

</div>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.name">
    {{ index }}: {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Official docs section - [**Mapping an Array to Elements with `v-for`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) (emphasis mine):

> Inside `v-for` blocks we have full access to parent scope properties. `v-for` also supports **an optional second argument for the index** of the current item.

Comment: Tom Fenech's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675988/how-to-get-the-v-for-index-in-vue-js#comment86366249_49675988) is very true and important. `:key="index"` doesn't really help much. Check out https://rimdev.io/the-v-for-key/ for an explanation as to why.

Comment: @AdamZerner Good tip. Prepending is really at odds with index as key. I will update the example

Comment: @acdcjunior could you please explain this part? "Inside v-for blocks we have full access to parent scope properties" what are the parent scope properties here? thank you for your time.

Comment: @KickButtowski in the example, the parent is the whole app, which only has `items`. If it had any other property, such properties would be available. Another example is if there is a `v-for` inside another `v-for`. In this case, the inner `v-for` has access to the variables declared in the outer `v-for`, its parent scope.

Comment: In Vue1 v-for the order of the values is different. It is (index, item) instead of (item, index)

Answer (score 15):

Use

```
 v-for="(value,name,index) in Object"
```

for Objects

```
v-for="(value,index) in Array"
```

for Arrays

Answer (score 7):

Create a new method:

```js
methods: {
    incrementIndex(key) {
        return key + 1;
    },
},
```

If the array keys are numbered, starting with zero like `items[0]`, `items[1]`, `etc..`, you can use the array's keys:

```html
<div v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
    {{ incrementIndex(key) }}
</div>
```

But if the array's keys are `typeof String` then you can do:

```html
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in items" :key="key">
    {{ incrementIndex(index) }}
</div>
```

The second version uses the `counter` from the `v-for` loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$index` to get the index of v-for.

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="`$index`"  >

</div>
```

and the other method:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"  >

</div>
```

Comment: The shorthand $index was unfortunately removed in Vue 2.x

Comment: using index as key is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 4):

**Updated Answer::**
You have indexed array as: `"["aaaa","bbbbb"]"` then you this script.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ["aaaa","bbbbb"]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    {{ index }} : {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div v-for="(item, index ) in arrayData" :key="index">
        <p>{{index+1}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has several  answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?