# Vue. How can I get prev and current value in loop v-for for comparing it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, v-for, vue-props

I have a part of the structure:

```
....
<template v-for="(item, INDEX) in someList">
    <template v-if="thisIsArrayList(item)">
        <template v-for="(_item) in item">
            <Component
                :item="_item"
                :key="_item.id"
                :myprop="checkIndex(INDEX)" - makes here some manipulation with prev and current INDEX and return iterration++ 0, 1
            ></Component>
        </template>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        ....
    </template>
</template>
....
```

The **INDEX** can be couple times with the same value like (22, 22, 22) the next step like (25, 25) and so on ..
so I tried in props:arrayId to compare **prevINDEX** with the **currentIndex** for passing it in child like new value with iterations++

for example:

**INDEX** couple times equal **22** --> change it on **0** and return this value --> the next **INDEX** couple time equal **55** --> change it on **1** and return this value --> and so on ...

How can  I do it in Vue?
Or maybe there is another solution for this logic?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear; would [the index `v-for` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675988/how-to-get-the-v-for-index-in-vue-js) help? Eg. `v-for="(item, index) in items"` will give the template in your loop access to the index value, which you could use to access the previous and/ or next value in `items`.

Comment: I edited the example .. so you can see what INDEX I'm meaning

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an explicit variable infact v-for itself provides you the ability to extract index during iteration

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <Component
        :item="item"
        :key="item.id"
    ></Component>
</template>
```

As per the above code, the arrayId prop is not necessary, since you are no longer going to compare the indexes [since you won't have redundant values]

Comment: I edited the example .. so you can see what INDEX I'm meaning

Comment: if someList is an array, they you won't have redundant values in INDEX

Comment: that depends on how many elements in the array you have. Child component takes props:INDEX  3 times with the same INDEX if array.length == 2

Comment: you don't get it

Comment: if that's an array then index won't be redundant, maybe the id attr inside each object could be redundant

Comment: is that what you mean?