# how can i access an index in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i'm trying to change the background color using for loop, first row should be white while second row show be  grey , but it keeps returning just the grey background on each row

here's my code

```
      <div
        class="
        row
        margin-top-4 margin-botton-4 margin-top-md-10 margin-bottom-10
      "
        :class="order % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-light-grey'"
        @click="navigateToOrderDetails(order)"
        v-for="order in allOrders"
        :key="order._id"
      >
         {{ order.description }}
       </div>
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: `v-for="(order, index) in allOrders"` then `:class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-light-grey'"`

Comment: sidenote you can do this with css, `.thing:nth-of-type(odd)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the v-for index in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675988/how-to-get-the-v-for-index-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0):

As `order` is an object, `order % 2 === 0` will always return false and it applied the else class which is `bg-light-grey`.

You should apply condition on the iteration `index`. Change your logic to **:**

```
<div
    v-for="(order, index) in allOrders"
    :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-light-grey'"
    :key="index"
>
   {{ order.description }}
</div>
```